# Liquibase includeAll incompatible with rollback and tagging?

Tags: liquibase

When using the includeAll option in the databaseChangeLog, is there any way to use rollback or tagging? It seems really nice to have all my changes in file 01.sql to 99.sql run in order. Do I have to go back to specifying the individual files and rollbacks to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SQL Format](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html)

e.g.:

`--changeset nvoxland:1
create table test1 (
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(255)
);
--rollback drop table test1;`

> As of Liquibase 2.0, Liquibase includes support for “plain SQL”
>   changelog files. These changelogs may be included from XML changelogs
>   and may contain arbitrary SQL statements. The statements are converted
>   to custom_sql refactorings.
>
> Formatted SQL files use comments to provide Liquibase with metadata.

Read more about [SQL Format](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html)